# Google Sheets API is Slow on Mac M1 Python

Tags: python, macos, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to do a simple reading from M1 MacBook Pro to google API.

Everything work fine but it take soooo long to do a simple reading , about 5-9 min.

Now , i'am trying to do it on my Windows Pc and it work fine.

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve it or even why ?

The Code :

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("jsonFile.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open_by_key("Rent").sheet1


data = sheet.get_all_records()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Sheets API v3 has been turned down since August 2, 2021. Instead of your current `scope`, you should use one of the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

More info at: [Sheets API docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#authorize_requests)