# Using googles apis in Python takes minutes to reply on apple m1 pro

Tags: python, apple-m1

I'm not sure of the relation, but since I upgraded Mac OS Ventura from 13.2.1 the use of any Google Cloud api gives me very high times, from 1-2 seconds it used to take to 5-6 minutes, it's like my script freezes.

This is something that happens to me with any of them, Dialogflow, Cloud Translation, Vertex AI... Searching I found that some people have the same problem, but no solution:

[Google Sheets API is Slow on Mac M1 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103112/google-sheets-api-is-slow-on-mac-m1-python)

[Extremely slow api calls caused by {method 'next_event' of 'grpc._cython.cygrpc.SegregatedCall' objects}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76335094/extremely-slow-api-calls-caused-by-method-next-event-of-grpc-cython-cygrpc)

I have tried all versions of python 3 from 3.8 to 3.11, to formatting the Mac could anyone help me with next steps or who can I turn to?

Answer (score 0):

Recently came across this same issue while using the `gsrpead` library. I am also on an M1 Pro Mac running Ventura 13.3.1. Turned out to be a local network issue for me. The things I tried that fixed the issue for me:

- use mobile hotspot/different network
- use a vpn
- run the script on Google Colab instead

I was also able to fix it with my main home network by tweaking some network settings. I manually configured my IPv6 to use the same Router details as the Router field:
[image]
Why this fixes it I have no idea tbh. But it did for me.